# R - Parse HTML only if http status response is 200

Tags: r, html-parsing, package

I have a dataframe `urls` which is just a list of URLs that I want to crawl to obtain a variable `pageName` defined in the source code. For this purpose I use the following code:

```
# Crawl Page Names
for(n in 1:length(urls$URL))
{
  if (domain(urls$URL[n])=="www.domain.com") {

  doc = readLines(con = file(as.character(urls$URL[n]), encoding = "UTF-8"))
  close(con)
  rowNumber = grep('s.pageName', doc)
  datalines = grep(pageNamePattern,doc[rowNumber],value=TRUE)
  gg = gregexpr(pageNamePattern,datalines)
  matches = mapply(getexpr,datalines,gg)
  matches = gsub(" ", "", matches[1], fixed = TRUE)
  result = gsub(pageNamePattern,'\\1',matches)
  names(result) = NULL
  urls$pageName[n] = stri_unescape_unicode(result[1])

  } else {

    urls$pageName[n] <- NA

  }
}
```

`if (domain(urls$URL[n])=="www.domain.com")` uses the function `domain` included in the [`urltools`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/urltools/urltools.pdf) package and let me crawl just those URLs where I know the pageName variable is defined, which are those in a specific domain.

However, my code is interrupted if the parsed page's http status response returns a 4XX Client Error or a 5XX Server error.

I would like to add a second if to the code for doing the crawl only if the http status response of `con` is 200 (OK). Does someone have an idea on how to do it or which package or functions to use?

Comment: you should read up on the `httr` and `rvest` pkgs. The way you're "parsing" web pages is fraught with peril. it also helps folks is you can use real URLs. my first inclination whenever i don't see real sites is that you're trying to violate the terms of service of another site since it's rare that one has to scrape an internal site (which is the only other valid reason to hide the URL IMO).

Comment: Thanks for your orientation about `httr` and `rvest`. I will take a deeper look at it, but I think that I can use the `http_status` function to check if the site responds with 200. But you are right. My way to read up code isn't the cleanest one. And don´t. I am not trying to violate any ToS :). The company, a client of us, is just very concern about its privacy. The only reason why I need to crawl its content is because we get a list of URLs but the Web Analytics Tool don't save those URLs but custom ones writen by a JavaScript. The only way to connect these 2 variables is scraping the web